# CSS div following width of previous div in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, width, css

Here is the link :
www.guidegather.com

(sorry, tried posting image but cannot)

If you look at the footer section, it appears correctly in all major browser (including IE9) but in IE7, the width of the div#mainfooter follows the max-width of .center class instead of extending horizontally to fill the space.

Here is the CSS :

```
.center{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 50px;
        max-width:960px;
}
#mainfooter{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#CCC;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Here is how the HTML roughly looks like :

```
<body>
<div class="center">
Something here
</div>
<div id="mainfooter">
    <div class="center">
    Something here
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the div#mainfooter is independent of the previous div, but the width is restricted to the max-width of the previous div (and child div). Any solution to this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So, the solution is to add 'display:block' to #mainfooter. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Use the checkmark beneath an answer's score to mark it accepted, rather than tagging your question "Solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to add `display:block` to #mainfooter. Hope this helps anyone facing this issue in the future and great thanks for those who tried helping me

Answer (score 0):

Since #mainfooter's rules will take priority over any inherited rules, you could specify a width for #mainfooter (`width: 100%`, or barring that, `max-width: 100%`). That should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it doesn't work (whether I add width:100%, max-width:100% or width:1000px)

Comment: So I have just tried adding display:block and it works now even if I don't have width:100%. Thanks for helping :)